# NodeJS JSON.stringify of very long array of objects errors "invalid string length"

Tags: json, node.js

I've got a very long array of objects that is about 100,000 items in size, and just before I got to write it to file, I pass the data into JSON.stringify

I get this error:

```
JSON.stringify(
     ^
RangeError: Invalid string length
```

How can I stringify a very large json object successfully?

## Update:

since I initially had written this question, I've become more familiar with processing large amounts of data, and I prefer to use Apache Spark for this process. In Spark, it is customary to not use large JSON arrays, but rather a stream or file containing long strings of JSON, one object per line. A file would look like this:

```
{"name":"kristian", "favoriteSong":"enter sandman"}
{"name":"joshua", "favoriteSong":"penny lane"}
{"name":"susan", "favoriteSong":"all about that bass"}
```

This is good because:

- you can arbitrarily deal with files that are terabytes large, and just as easily do some logicless file splitting and turn that into a thousand smaller files, were the logic is to simply break the file at some line break number N.
- This is better you wont ever have the potentially horrible issue of having a corrupted data file on your hands, caused by an un-closed JSON array.
- a large JSON array in a file tends to not have line breaks, and thus large files are a pain to open in VIM or other editors because it tries to load the whole thing into memory, as opposed to a file with linebreaks, where it can easily load the first 10 lines or so to the screen without issue.

Comment: Uh, make two separate objects of the org obj, stringify each then concat results back together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I stringify a very large json object successfully?

In parts? E.g., break the array up into smaller parts, use `JSON.stringify` on the smaller parts, and append each segment to the file (you'll have to do some `[`, `,`, and `]` handling).

Answer (score 15):

I find **[JSONStream](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream)** to be a reliable alternative to the native **JSON.stringify** that works well with large objects. For example:

```
var fileSystem = require( "fs" );
var JSONStream = require( "JSONStream" );
var records = [
    { id: 1, name: "Terminator" },
    { id: 2, name: "Predator" },
    { id: 3, name: "True Lies" },
    { id: 4, name: "Running Man" },
    { id: 5, name: "Twins" }
    // .... hundreds of thousands of records ....
];

var transformStream = JSONStream.stringify();
var outputStream = fileSystem.createWriteStream( __dirname + "/data.json" );
transformStream.pipe( outputStream );    
records.forEach( transformStream.write );
transformStream.end();

outputStream.on(
    "finish",
    function handleFinish() {
        console.log("Done");
    }
);
```

Took the sample code from [here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3232-parsing-and-serializing-large-objects-using-jsonstream-in-node-js.htm).

Comment: This didn't work for me. I have nested array of Objects that is about 70 Megabytes of data. Could you help me with that?

Comment: This works great, but be aware that node.js doesn't seem to write anything to disk while you are busy filling up the transformStream. So either start your process with a high memory limit or pause occasionally to give the nodejs event loop some time to empty the pipe.