# How to split javascript object into smaller parts

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, stringify

I am trying to JSONify a Javascript object only to get "Invalid String Length" error. I decided to break the object up into smaller parts, use JSON.stringify on the smaller parts, and append each segment to the file.

I first converted the javascript object into an array and split them into smaller parts.

`{'key1': [x, y, z], 'key2' : [p, q, l], ...... }` - a sample of original object in JSON notation. Each character `x, y, z, p, q, l` is an abbreviation of a base 64 string that is long enough to cause the string length overflow problem.

`[ ['key1', x], ['key1', y], ['key1', z], ['key2', p], .......` ] - array converted

```
var arrays = []
while (arrayConvertedObject.length > 0)
    arrays.push(arrayConvertedObject.slice(0, 2))
}
```

Then I was going to create a javascript object for each of the smaller arrays in `arrays` to use JSON.stringify individually.

```
[["key1", x], ["key1", y]] - array 1
[["key1", z], ["key2", p]] - array 2
```

When I convert each smaller array into a Javascript object and use JSON.stringify, I get :

```
{"key1": [x, y]} - string 1
{"key1": [z], "key2": [p]} - string 2
```

The problem is that the string concatenation with extra manipulation of `},{` will not retain the original data :

```
{"key1": [x, y], "key1": [z], "key2": [p]}
```

When I want `obj["key1"]` to have `[x, y, z]`, the JSON above will be parsed into `obj["key1"] = [z]`.

If I do not use JSON.stringify on the smaller objects, it will defeat my original goal of JSONifying a large javascript object. But if I do so, I cannot concatenate JSONified small objects that have duplicate keys.

Is there any better way to deal with JSON.stringify "Invalid String Length" error? If not, is there a way to concatenate JSONified objects without overriding duplicate keys?

Thank you for reading a lengthy question. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please add the original object, you like to manipulate and the wanted result.

Comment: Thanks for reading my question. Just updated my question to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: while i get the problem, i miss the part, wehre you put the values together again. do make a JSON (the string) with the parts and parse it for an object? or do you create an object out of the particles?

Comment: If I try to create an object out of smaller javascript objects and JSON.stringify the large object, I get "Invalid String Length" error. Therefore, I am using JSON.stringify on smaller objects to concatenate the JSON strings to make one JSONified object.

Comment: My approach is based on this stackoverflow [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676674/nodejs-json-stringify-of-very-long-array-of-objects-errors-invalid-string-lengt) to solve string length overflow issue in JSON.stringify.

Comment: Please post original JSON before you do anything to it.

Comment: Assuming splitting is the plan, why don't you loop over the keys of the original object and make *one* object per key with a value that is the original array of that key? Then if you stringify the resulting pieces none of them will have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below uses direct string maniuplation.

Haven't done any performance comparisons.

```js
var x="X", y="Y", z="Z", p="P";

// your starting arrays 
var subArrs = [ ['key1', x], ['key1', y], ['key1', z], ['key2', p]];

// the result should be in this string
var jsonString = "{}";

// take each subArray
subArrs.map(function(subArr) {
  var key = subArr[0];
  var val = subArr[1];
  // try to look for the key in the string
  var keyMatcher = '"'+key+'":\\[';
  var endOfObjectMatcher = '\\}$';
  var regexStr = keyMatcher + '|' + endOfObjectMatcher;
  jsonString = jsonString.replace(new RegExp(regexStr), function(match){
      if (match=='}') { 
        // the end of the object has been matched, 
        // so simply append the new key-value pair
        return ',"'+key+'":['+JSON.stringify(val)+"]}";
      } else { 
        // an existing key has been found, 
        // so prepend the value to the beginning of the array
        // (match contains something like: '"somekey":['
        return match + JSON.stringify(val) + ",";
      }
    });
});

// replace the falsely added first comma in the object
jsonString = jsonString.replace('{,','{');

// print it here
document.write(">>" + jsonString + "<br/>");
```

```css
body {
   font-family: monospace;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal comportement.

> `{"key1": [1, 2], "key1": [3], "key2": [4]}`

You define 2 times the `key1` attribute. But each key must be unique. So the second declaration override the first.

It think you must change your concatenation method to concatenate each JSON string into an array like this :

```
[
  {"key1": [1, 2]},
  {"key1": [3], "key2": [4]}
]
```

What is you Node.JS version ?

> I am trying to JSONify a Javascript object only to get "Invalid String
>   Length" error.

This is an old issue of V8 engine, see [issue #14170](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/14170).
You may be considered to try on a greater version of Node.JS.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.