# swagger error "Uncaught RangeError: Invalid string length" in mvc angularjs mix project

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, swagger

I have a project in mvc5 and anguarjs mix and here I am trying to add swagger
I had installed the latest Swashbuckle
and tried this API which is working http://localhost:6790/swagger/docs/v1
and I could say that my json is valid and checked on https://editor.swagger.io

but when I tied this on http://localhost:6790/swagger/ui/index (view)
this shows error

```
Uncaught RangeError: Invalid string length
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at t.exports.u.getModelSampleJSON (swagger-ui-min-js:formatted:12777)
    at new t.exports (swagger-ui-min-js:formatted:12498)
    at swagger-ui-min-js:formatted:10638
    at r (swagger-ui-min-js:formatted:16772)
    at Object.forEach (swagger-ui-min-js:formatted:17559)
    at swagger-ui-min-js:formatted:10630
    at swagger-ui-min-js:formatted:17468
    at r (swagger-ui-min-js:formatted:17002)
    at swagger-ui-min-js:formatted:17447
```

I had tried to search online but did not get any solution for this

so here anyone has any idea about this matter and how to solve this problem

Comment: Try checking for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655446/json-stringify-range-error.

Comment: this solution is nice but here i could not directly change in Swashbuckle  swagger  api