# Nuget package"Swagger-Net" swagger-ui default ui page Modification In Asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui

I am having a project in asp.net mvc5 and added swagger which Swagger-Net NuGet package (https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net)

[image]

and here I need to remove HTML section which is inside of red rectangle 
this is default UI provided by   Swagger-Net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either replace index.html with your own entirely or use CSS to hide the div.

To replace index.html, do something like this.

```
httpConfiguration
     .EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "A title for your API"))
     .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
         {
             c.CustomAsset("index", yourAssembly, "YourWebApiProject.SwaggerExtensions.index.html");
         });
```

Replacing the entire index.html file may be a bit of an overkill for this and will mean you need to maintain this as Swagger updates it.  So, if you wanted to just hide the block you could do that with CSS.

Specify a custom stylesheet like so:

```
httpConfiguration
    .EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "A title for your API"))
    .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
        {
            c.InjectStylesheet(containingAssembly, "Swagger-Net.Dummy.SwaggerExtensions.testStyles1.css");
        });
```

and then in your custom stylesheet (testStyles1.css) put:

```
information-container { 
    display: none; 
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net/wiki/3-Customizing-the-swagger-ui#provide-your-own-index-file) for more information about both options.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @Chris.ZA
 and I will prefer adding CSS trick 
here I have another thread about swagger in asp.net 
here before I am using Swashbuckle nuget and having the problem  this ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/53169601/7961948 ) and this may come from there is much number of API's in JSON string (maybe as I search on the web)
if you had time you may check this :-)!